# How to pronounce the American "em'" in "them"?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

I just can't pronounce it properly..

How to pronounce the AmE's "em" in "them"? I always pronounced it like the "un" in "fun" or the "um" in dumb.

Comment: How do you pronounce the letter '*m*'?

Comment: @Jim like the m in "dumb".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If stressed, it's the ordinary ‘short e’, IPA /ɛ/, as in *dress*:

> I gave it to **them**, not him.

If unstressed, it takes a [reduced vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Reduced_vowels), the  ‘schwa’ (/ə/) heard in the first syllable of *about* and the last syllable of *coda*. This is very close to the /ʌ/ in *fun*, as that is pronounced in General American; but various dialects pronounce /ʌ/ differently, so you can't make that a general rule. Usually, too, the initial consonant is dropped:

> Give ‘em hell, Harry!

And that phrase, in fact, where the /v/ and the /m/ are articulated at the same point, will often elide even further, eliminating the /v/ (and the /h/) and reducing the schwa to a barely discernible glide:

> Gi'mell, Harry!

Comment: Don't forget about the pen-pin merger.  In the South, a stressed "em" is /ɪm/, not /ɛm/.

Comment: @dan04 In my part of the South it was a diphthong, /ɛɪm/, before /m/.